# Qt / C++ QImage sometimes file is not loaded. But file is accessible

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qt4.8

In our C++/Qt4.8 application we are using QImage to add images to our documents we print. Sometimes we expierence issues with printing the image, and the image will be printed out blank (just a empty page).

We added logging into our application and added an audit log on our resources folder where the images are.

We initialize our image in this way. And pass it as argument to mPainter (instance of QPainter)

```
QImage image( strImage );
mPainter.drawImage( QRect( 0, 0, pageRect().width(), pageRect().height() ), image );
```

The drawImage fuction of mPainter will call the following QPainter function :

```
inline void QPainter::drawImage(const QRect &r, const QImage &image)
{
    drawImage(r, image, QRectF(0, 0, image.width(), image.height()));
}
```

The windows audit shows us that the application successfully tried to acces the files.

But sometimes the following code will returns false and goes into the else:

```
QImage* imageToPrint = new QImage;
if (imageToPrint->load("C:/ApplicationName/Resources/page-001.jpg"))
{
    //fuction body 
} 
else 
{
    if (QFile::exists("C:/ApplicationName/Resources/page-001-copy.jpg"))
    {
        //Copy the image and try to print with this one.
        QFile::copy("C:/ApplicationName/Resources/page-001-copy.jpg", "C:/ApplicationName/Resources/page-001-unixtimestamp.jpg");
        printImage("C:/ApplicationName/Resources/page-001-unixtimestamp.jpg");
        QFile::remove("C:/ApplicationName/Resources/page-001-unixtimestamp.jpg");
    } 
}
```

The strangest thing is that the application can access, copy and delete files in the directory. But sometimes can't read the data from the file. Even the newly created copy with the unixtimestamp can't be loaded (But does exist following the code) and will print a blank page.

Has anybody has this problem? Our does anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know qt, but you should check the return value of `QFile::copy` and if it returns `false` find out more about the cause of the error (not sure how to do this with qt, but e.g. in raw Windows API you would use the [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360) function).

Comment: My first guess with seemingly random file read/write failures in windows is that your anti virus is getting in the way. You could try [QImageReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html) which should at least give you an error message

Comment: @AlanBirtles AV software is often good for any (bad) surprise. Sometimes, it even doesn't need AV S/W for this. It happens that I describe code in an Excel table which is transformed via awk script into C++ or simply used in X macros. Excel is very possessive as well. As long as I don't close the file, awk or VS simply fails to access - something which bothered me sometimes... ;-) Similar issue: removing files fails - File Explorer still owns handles on them. (I'm working daily in Windows but somethimes it drives me crazy.)